# BPP(complexity) with binary form of number

Tags: computational-complexity, turing-machines, computational-algebra

For any language $L \subseteq \mathbb{B^{*}}$ we define language $L^{log}$ as set $\{\overline{a}\overline{b} | \overline{a} \in L, \, \overline{b} - \text{binary form of number}\,\, |\overline{a}|\}.$

Prove:

if $L \in \mathbf{BPP}$, then $L^{log} \in \mathbf{BPP}$.

Any hint how to start it?

Comment: I think you mean the binary form? This will be similar to the other question. If you are stuck, maybe start by proving that if $L \in P$, then $L^{\log} \in P$. To do so start with a polynomial time Turing machine that recognizes $L$, and modify it to recognize $L^{\log}$. You (probably) don't have to describe the specification of the machine in detail (if this is the confusing point), just describe the algorithm and check that it runs in polynomial time. You can use the machine that recognizes $L$ as a subroutine that your algorithm calls.

Comment: @Lorenzo well, I get your suggestion, but how should I use probability here? BPP is class with probability Turing machine.

Comment: You just have to check the false positive / false negative rates for the algorithm that solves the new problem using the old one. There's very little that will be different from solving this problem over $P$. Note that you can check the $\bar{b}$ part deterministically...